# Jquery Mobile and 404 Pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile and I'm wondering the best way to remove the error dialogue from showing and send the user to a actual error page instead.

Thanks for your help

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the `$.mobile.pageloadfailed` function.

So, for example:

```
$( document ).bind( "pageloadfailed", function( event, data ){

    // Let the framework know we're going to handle things.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Change the page
    if(!$.mobile.changePage('404.html')){
        // If it fails, call reject
        data.deferred.reject( data.absUrl, data.options );
    }

});
```

[jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html)